# Url rewriting affects other linksthe

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

Am using url reqritting with following rule :

> <rule source="(.)/galary.aspx" destination="galary.aspx?$1"/>

The links are in MasterPage where I have set achor tags like :

> <a href="/2/galary.aspx">Galary 2</a>
>   Which internally deals as :
>   /galary.aspx?2

The page is working fine for me with this rule. But the other link breaks and the images are not shown on pages like.

When checked the source code of the page, I found that the links of all images and other Menus are changed in the same format as, I applied rules for the url.
Like : actual images path: /images/img.gif but now these are : /2/images/img.gif

I manually set the absolute path for everything then images appeared but its not a solution.

Waiting for your inputs

Comment: Still did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is simple, your rule match every links because of dot **(.)**. change rule you need a regular expression that match with number first:

```
(\d+)/gallery\.aspx
```

replace your rule with this and it only match with **Number/Gallery.aspx**